# Find a scalar field that satisfies the following conditions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**QUESTION**

> Find a scalar field $f$ that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1. Partial derivatives equal to $0$.
> 2. $f'(\vec x,\vec v)=3$, for $\vec v=\left(\frac {\sqrt2} 2,\frac {\sqrt2} 2\right)$.

**ATTEMPT**

$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}=0\implies f=\alpha(y)$, analogous for $y$, so I get $f=\beta(x)$, substracting and rearranging, $\alpha(y)=\beta(x)$ so they must be constants, but this obviously doesn't satisfy the second condition. How can I solve this?

Comment: By $f'(\vec x,\vec v)=3$ you are talking about the directional derivative, right?

Comment: Correct! ${}{}{}$

Comment: You are correct.  If the partials are identically zero everywhere, then $f$ is constant.  And therefore, it's directional derivative is also $0$ for any direction.

Comment: Right, it doesn't seem to make sense that the directional derivative for a constant function is positive, so perhaps the question is incorrect?

Comment: I thought that maybe from my conclusions I could only say that if such an $f$ exists, then it would have to be discontinuous, but I'm not sure im right. @Dr.MV doesn't that hold iff $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: Well, the directional derivative is still the dot product of the gradient of the scalar field, and the direction vector. So it is in this case $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}$ + $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}$

Comment: This should not ever be equal to $3$

Comment: Hmm my def of the $f'(x,v)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+hv)-f(x)} h$, which equals $\nabla f \cdot v$ only if $f$ is differentiable